# How to use variables in NGINX RTMP and what do they do?

Tags: environment-variables, nginx, encoding, rtmp

I've been trying to get my head around how the variables work specifically $name and $app. What are the benefits of using variables within a multi-stream and multiple stream qualities? This is the documentation I am referring to > https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#exec_push

Would someone be able to share several examples please as I cannot find any examples on the internet.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *"What are the benefits of using variables within a multi-stream and multiple stream qualities?"* - The point of the variables is so (some) specific details don't need to appear in a configuration (i.e. Nginx substitutes the appropriate details/values for the corresponding variables for each stream). That is, they help create "generic" commands that can be applied to more than one stream without necessarily altering the command for each case.

Comment: Are you able to provide examples within a configuration please?

Answer (score 0):

exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://ip-or-domain:1935/live/$name -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -g 10 -s 300x200 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f mpegts scheme://ip-or-domain:port/$app/$name 2>>/var/log/ffmpeg-$name.log;

Try that example. i copied straight from the link you provided, put it in my nginx.conf and it has worked to push the stream to another location.

I was actually looking for a solution - as you were - and this one has worked for me. you can tweak the ffmpeg settings as you wish.